# Python subprocess subprocess.check_output and journalctl cursor

Tags: python, subprocess

I am working on script that will filter specific logs from journalctl. For position from last run i am using cursor, which point to specific line in journalctl

To get journal i am using:

```
journal = subprocess.check_output(['journalctl', '-c "s=b5b4b91f4c7b4818b65091488f050d2c;i=cab;b=2aa19337e07b45a3b1512f0cbfb37022;m=12e4d43961;t=56e92fc5786c7;x=a68e963efa2c81f4"'])
```

but i am getting error:

```
Failed to seek to cursor: Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GlobalLogger.py", line 28, in <module>
    journal = subprocess.check_output(['journalctl', '-c "s=b5b4b91f4c7b4818b65091488f050d2c;i=cab;b=2aa19337e07b45a3b1512f0cbfb37022;m=12e4d43961;t=56e92fc5786c7;x=a68e963efa2c81f4"'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['journalctl', '-c "s=b5b4b91f4c7b4818b65091488f050d2c;i=cab;b=2aa19337e07b45a3b1512f0cbfb37022;m=12e4d43961;t=56e92fc5786c7;x=a68e963efa2c81f4"']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

but when i put this command directly to command window:

```
journalctl -c "s=b5b4b91f4c7b4818b65091488f050d2c;i=cab;b=2aa19337e07b45a3b1512f0cbfb37022;m=12e4d43961;t=56e92fc5786c7;x=a68e963efa2c81f4"
```

It works perfectly fine.

also for example:

```
subprocess.check_output(['journalctl', '-q'])
```

works fine

Is it possible that its too long argument for  subprocess.check_output to handle?
Or where can be problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
['journalctl', '-c "s=b5b4b91f4c7b4818b65091488f050d2c;i=cab;b=2aa19337e07b45a3b1512f0cbfb37022;m=12e4d43961;t=56e92fc5786c7;x=a68e963efa2c81f4"']
```

should be

```
['journalctl', '-c', '"s=b5b4b91f4c7b4818b65091488f050d2c;i=cab;b=2aa19337e07b45a3b1512f0cbfb37022;m=12e4d43961;t=56e92fc5786c7;x=a68e963efa2c81f4"']
```

Every single parameters should be splited.

Comment: Thank you very much :) i thought that parameter and value should be as one :)